# How do I Recode Values in a Column in Pandas? (My Attempts at Doing So Aren't Working)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to Python and am having a problem trying to execute a very basic task in pandas. I am trying to create a new column (variable) called RACE which is based off of the values in RAC1P_RC1. I have tried every way to recode RACE (loc, apply, lambda), but it will not update its values at all, even when the argument is true. For example, I tried to use the code

```
def f(x):
  if x['RAC1P_RC1'] == 1: return 1
  else: return 0

acs['RACE'] = acs.apply(f, axis=1)
```

And when I look at the dataframe, all cases in RACE have a value of 0, even in cases where RAC1P_RC1 equals 1. There seems to be something very basic I'm missing here, since this is one of the simplest tasks in pandas, and I'm not able to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the datatype of 'RAC1P_RC1' column, make sure it's not an object data type. If its object datatype then the condition (if x['RAC1P_RC1'] == 1) will always return False.
2. Also, you could use .loc to make the code faster as follows:

   ```
    mask = (acs['RAC1P_RC1'] == 1)
    acs.loc[mask,'RACE'] = 1
    acs.loc[~mask,'RACE'] = 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your condition directly and that will give you a Series of True/False then typecast that Series to int via `astype()` method and you will get corrosponding binary values:

```
acs['RACE'] =acs['RAC1P_RC1'].eq(1).astype(int)
```

OR

you can also use `view()` method in place of `astype()` for achieving the same:

```
acs['RACE'] =acs['RAC1P_RC1'].eq(1).view('i1')
```